# C# App using clickonce not installing on newly installed Windows 10 Systems

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I am not sure if my problem is user error or just another "microsoft changed the default settings" bug.

We have a 2 relatively big internal apps. Both use Net 7, C# and WPF at the moment and get installed and updated via ClickOnce from a Networkshare.

One of the 2 apps works perfectly on all pcs,
The other one doesn't start after installing it on newly installed PCs. Most of our pcs are on
10.0.19044 Build 19044, where it works perfectly, the newly installed PCs are on
10.0.19045 Build 19045, where the App doesn't start.

The installer completes and closes without any error messages and every time a User clicks on the App it doesn't even open

I tried:
Setting the Application to a higher target os version
setting the application to Net 6 instead of Net 7

Both did not result in a working installer.

Every other setting i could think of is identical in both apps, so i am not sure where the Problem could be.

I can start the App using the link in Appdata, this is however not an acceptable solution since it keeps the app from updating and I can't feasibly to this on every pc the app runs on.